# .NET Core 3.1 and Could not load file or assembly System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core

What Nuget package is `System.Data.Entity` in?

I am converting a .NET Framework 4.5 app to .NET Core 3.1.  In .NET Framework, it is using `System.Linq.Dynamic`, and the app is crashing when running this code:

```
var results = report.GroupBy(filter.ID, "it")
                    .Select($"new (it.Key as MainID, it as MyModel)");
```

With this error message:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>      at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser..cctor()

Note: it does compile correctly

thanks

edit: The System.Linq.Dynamic Nuget package is installed.

Comment: You can have a look at [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/) package and this GitHub [repo](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) I'm not sure, that they are same, but it should help you

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski that did, had to add .AsQueryable() but it worked perfectly!  if you add this as an answer I will give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `System.Data.Entity` and `System.Linq.Dynamic` assemblies belongs to .NET Framework. For .NET Core you can try to use [`System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/)  package, it's compatible with .NET Standard. Its GitHub [repo](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) says, that it's .NET core port of the assembly for the .NET 4.0 Dynamic language functionality.

Answer (score 1):

One point I would like to add to @PavelAnikhouski, a very minor change needs to be made to the code.  You have to add `AsQueryable()` to the collection.

```
var results = report.AsQueryable()
                .GroupBy(filter.ID, "it")
                .Select($"new (it.Key as MainID, it as MyModel)");
```