# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Entity 4.0.0.0 in azure function referencing a class library

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

Getting this error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException   HResult=0x80070002   Message=Could
> not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot
> find the file specified.   Source=...   StackTrace:    at ....

I create an azure function referencing a class library.

I checked on the class library, `System.Data.Entity` is being referenced.
But when I run the azure function, I get this error.

What might be wrong here?

The Azure function is on .Net Core 3.1.
The referenced class library (as a project so I can debug it) is on .Net Framework 4.7.2

Is a class library of .net Framework 4.7.2 supported when referenced on .net Core 3.1 (why its not loading System.Data.Entity)?

Comment: Could you please give us more information so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Can you post your code, and how did you import the class library, and which class libraries were imported?

Comment: I updated my question to include additional answers for the comments here

Comment: @Alexander, This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58658260/is-it-possible-to-reference-net-framework-4-7-2-class-library-from-an-asp-net-c) may solve your confusion, we can see from the post: `.NET Core doesn't support inclusion of .NET Framework libraries.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58658260/is-it-possible-to-reference-net-framework-4-7-2-class-library-from-an-asp-net-c) we can know:

> .NET Core doesn't support inclusion of .NET Framework libraries. Period. However, .NET Core supports .NET Standard, and since .NET Framework also implements .NET Standard, Microsoft made a special exception in the compiler to allow you include .NET Framework libraries, with the caveat that they may not actually function at all or totally. You get a warning to this effect when you include a .NET Framework library in a .NET Core project, and it's on you to ensure that the library works correctly end-to-end.

Because `.NET Core` supports `.NET Standard` library, you can use the package of `.NET Standard`. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59632579/net-core-3-1-and-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-entity-version-4) is similar to your problem, his solution may inspire you.

Comment: Thanks, I think I like that approach.. to make it .net standard, then to retest if the .net FW libraries will work